# Why does my Laptop CPU throttles itself until I pull and reinsert Power Cable?

Tags: arch-linux, cpu, power-management, laptop

my Laptop (HP Envy x360) with an AMD Ryzen 5 2500U is at a stable ~2,4 GHz when under load but after some time it always drops to 1,2 GHz and won't go up even though plugged in, 100% Battery charge and "normal" Temperatures (67 C).
The only fix I found until now is pulling and reinserting the power cable, then it goes to what I guess is the boost clock for like 30 seconds ~2,8 GHz, and then it stays at the normal 2,4 GHz for a few minutes until it drops to 1,2 GHz and the cycle repeats.

---

What I found:

- Restarting tlp.service has the same effect like pulling the power cable, CPU returns to normal clock for a few minutes (see example below)
- No difference between the throttled and normal cpu clock in tlp statistics:

TLP Statistics complete dump: https://pastebin.com/E0zByf3Q

---

What I tried without success:

- Better cooling (always stays at 65-80 C°)
- Memtest64 no errors
- No related settings in BIOS (Only "Fan always on" which is turned off)
- ASPM is enabled and set to performance
- TLP persistent default is set to always use AC Mode
- All TLP Settings are set to performance or equivalent high setting

---

Example Screenshots while Stress testing with tui:

- Throttled (after a few minutes of stress)
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VpqM.jpg
- After pulling plug for 3 seconds (Boost Clock I guess)
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipMKk.jpg
- After 30 seconds for a few minutes until throttling again
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUg8i.jpg

---

Any ideas on what I should try before reinstalling Arch? If there are other Logs or Data that might be helpful, I will add them.